# Cannot get value of Node object

Tags: nodes

I'm trying to retrieve a value from a [Node object](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21Entity%21Node.php/8.6.x). It looks like the value is there, when debugging and checking out the object. But somehow it cannot be accessed.

Trying to get the field:

```
// $this->entityManager is an instance of EntityTypeManagerInterface 
$node = $this->entityManager->getStorage('node')->load($nodeId);

// hasField always returns FALSE
$node->hasField('field_google_hire_identifier');
// $node->get('field_google_hire_identifier'); returns unknown field error
```

Debugging [$node->hasField](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21ContentEntityBase.php/function/ContentEntityBase%3A%3AhasField/8.6.x), looking inside [getFieldDefinition](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21ContentEntityBase.php/function/ContentEntityBase%3A%3AgetFieldDefinition/8.6.x):

```
  public function getFieldDefinition($name) {
    if (!isset($this->fieldDefinitions)) {
      $this->getFieldDefinitions();
    }
    if (isset($this->fieldDefinitions[$name])) {
      // This code should be executed, but it is not.
      return $this->fieldDefinitions[$name];
    }
  }
```

[image: Debugging values]

The second if statement content is not executed, with my understanding it should be.

The node was created with migrate.

I disabled APC and Opcache.

Comment: I ran into something similar with migrate - if the field was on 2 node types, then field definition was returning null no matter what. And I was able to assert this in a [kernel test I was making for organic group migration](https://github.com/Gizra/og/pull/432) but I have not been able to reproduce it in a test in core only. I think perhaps there are some missing configuration during some migrations, but that's as far as I have gotten. I don't think this is on-topic and is probably related to whichever module provided those fields.

Comment: Alright, I'll probably dig inside the database to find out more.
I created the field (plain text) with the UI.
But it looks fine when I step through the code with the debugger. All the data is there (on the node object). Strangely I can't get it.

Comment: Looking forward to it. If you can reproduce it in core somewhere please file an issue and ping me here.

Comment: It looks like your issue was unrelated, @Orlando, but I realized I *did* file a core issue related to field definitions being null (not your issue), and did some work on it last year. My memory is just bad - https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3008202. Adding this for posterity and my own memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field name string contained a [right to left mark](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200f/index.htm).
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54653637/cannot-get-array-key-array-key-not-set/54655517#54655517 to find out how to remove it